# Writing a working sample PHP app for Quickbooks Online

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm getting started writing an app using the PHP SDK.  I'm trying to start off with a simple page that connects to my data and lists customers.

I'm using code from one of the examples in the _samples folder.  So far, it seems to get the Realm ID, creates a new OAuthRequestValidator, ServiceContext, and DataService, all without errors.

The call to Findall to get customers isn't coming back -- I'm assuming it has an exception.

My questions:  is the approach I'm taking (a minimal example script which connects and queries) skipping some essential steps?  Is the problem that I'm not putting the "Connect to QuickBooks" button up and going through that process?

Finally, is there a sample PHP app that I can start with (after changing the keys and tokens)?

Thanks,

-brian

Comment: Believe it or not, intuit has excellent integration support. If you ask them they may provide you with all the help you need. They helped me develop an app above my expectations.

Comment: There's no way to actually contact Intuit directly to ask them that I'm aware of - they are actively encouraging people to post on forums and StackOverflow with questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an open-source PHP DevKit that is popular and has lots of examples in it (including what you're asking for).

You can find the code on GitHub:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

If you follow the quick-start guide (which basically involves swapping out some URLs and tokens) you'll end up with a working mini-app that has a working "Connect to QuickBooks" button, Blue Dot menu, disconnect script, and a big pile of example data exchange scripts for adding/querying/updating customers, invoices, etc.

Quick start guide:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start

Lots and lots of example code:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3

Comment: last github link results to 404